# JSP class not found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.version2.scheduleGuide.scheduleGuideTreeview_jsp

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

when I try to access one page , I'm getting two errors. Same build is working fine in my local windows environment. It is failing in linux. Apache-tomcat-6.0.37 . Here is the stack.

```
ERROR org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext- JSPException while including path '/degreeView/viewStudentInfo.jsp'. 
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: ServletException while including page.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:102)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:457)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.common.tiles.mainLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(mainLayout_jsp.java:386)
    at org.apache.jsp.common.tiles.mainLayout_jsp._jspService(mainLayout_jsp.java:315)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:417)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:368)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.util.TilesDispatchServlet.doGet(TilesDispatchServlet.java:83)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1054)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    at com.apollo.s3.struts.action.S3RequestProcessor.process(S3RequestProcessor.java:26)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1192)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:412)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1054)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    at com.apollo.s3.struts.action.S3RequestProcessor.process(S3RequestProcessor.java:26)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1192)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:412)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1054)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    at com.apollo.s3.struts.action.S3RequestProcessor.process(S3RequestProcessor.java:26)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1192)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:412)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.apollogrp.sso.client.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.apollo.s3.filter.LoadTimeFilter.doFilter(LoadTimeFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.apollo.s3.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /degreeView/viewStudentInfo.jsp at line 16

13: 
14: <div id="viewStudentInfo" style="width: 100%" >
15:            <div id="degreeAuditReportContainer">
16:                 <jsp:include page="/version2/scheduleGuide/degreeAuditReport.jsp"
17:                              flush="false" />
18:             </div>
19:             <div id="viewGGroundStudentInfoScheduleDisplayContainer">


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:621)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:98)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /version2/scheduleGuide/degreeAuditReport.jsp at line 54

51:           <td width="367" align="right" valign="top">
52:           <!-- Audit and Guide -->
53:               <div id="scheduleGuideSection" style="visibility:hidden">
54:                 <jsp:include page="/version2/scheduleGuide/scheduleGuide.jsp" flush="false"/>
55:               </div>
56:           <!-- Audit and Guide -->
57:           </td>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.degreeView.viewStudentInfo_jsp._jspService(viewStudentInfo_jsp.java:67)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /version2/scheduleGuide/scheduleGuide.jsp at line 329

326:        <tr>
327:            <td align="left">
328:                <div id="scheduleGuideContainer">
329:                    <jsp:include page="/version2/scheduleGuide/scheduleGuideTreeview.jsp"/>
330:                </div>
331:            </td>
332:        </tr>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.version2.scheduleGuide.degreeAuditReport_jsp._jspx_meth_logic_005fequal_005f0(degreeAuditReport_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jsp.version2.scheduleGuide.degreeAuditReport_jsp._jspService(degreeAuditReport_jsp.java:127)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:156)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jsp.version2.scheduleGuide.scheduleGuide_jsp._jspService(scheduleGuide_jsp.java:493)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    ... 132 more
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
    ... 146 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.version2.scheduleGuide.scheduleGuideTreeview_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
//2nd error
 ERROR org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport- IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/degreeView/viewStudentInfo.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/degreeView/viewStudentInfo.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
//3rd error
 ERROR org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport- Error during rendering
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/degreeView/viewStudentInfo.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:84)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JSPException while including path '/degreeView/viewStudentInfo.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:91)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:457)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
```

I tried deleting the work folder and any temp folder on the server. This class exists on the following path in work folder org.apache.jsp.version2.scheduleGuide.scheduleGuideTreeview_jsp.